# How to call this method from library?

Tags: java, android, syntax

I am not sure how to call this method from another class, `deleteSurroundingText(int leftLength, int rightLength)` It is in Class EmulatorView in a library. But it also seems nested in some other classes, so I can't say something like `EmulatorView.deleteSurroundingText(1,1);`

Here is what it says about the method:

**boolean jackpal.androidterm.emulatorview.EmulatorView.onCreateInputConnection(...).new BaseInputConnection() {...}.deleteSurroundingText(int leftLength, int rightLength)**

```
boolean jackpal.androidterm.emulatorview.EmulatorView.onCreateInputConnection(...).new BaseInputConnection() {...}.deleteSurroundingText(int leftLength, int rightLength)

Overrides: deleteSurroundingText(...) in BaseInputConnection
public boolean deleteSurroundingText (int beforeLength, int afterLength)
Added in API level 3
The default implementation performs the deletion around the current selection position of the editable text.

Parameters
beforeLength    The number of characters to be deleted before the current cursor position.
afterLength The number of characters to be deleted after the current cursor position.
```

Section of code:

```
public InputConnection onCreateInputConnection(EditorInfo outAttrs) {
        outAttrs.inputType = mUseCookedIme ?
                EditorInfo.TYPE_CLASS_TEXT :
                EditorInfo.TYPE_NULL;
        return new BaseInputConnection(this, true) {

            public boolean deleteSurroundingText(int leftLength, int rightLength) {
                  Log.w(TAG2, "in DeleteSurroundingText");
                if (LOG_IME) {
                    Log.w(TAG, "deleteSurroundingText(" + leftLength +
                            "," + rightLength + ")");
                }
                if (leftLength > 0) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < leftLength; i++) {
                        sendKeyEvent(
                            new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL));
                    }
                } else if ((leftLength == 0) && (rightLength == 0)) {
                    // Delete key held down / repeating
                    sendKeyEvent(
                        new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DEL));
                }
                // TODO: handle forward deletes.
                //int i = 1;
               //deleteSurroundingText(i, i);
                return true;
            }         
        };
    }
```

Thanks

Comment: "It is in Class EmulatorView in a library. But it also seems nested in some other classes" - What do you mean here, which classes?

Comment: Please post only relevant code... And you're not event using EmulatorView in the code you posted...

Comment: Maybe classes was the wrong word, it is inside InputConnection, and BaseInputConnection. I have edited out a lot of the non relevant code